# C++11 lambdas: member variable capture gotcha

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider this code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A(int data) : data_(data)
    { std::cout << "A(" << data_ << ")" << std::endl; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl; }
    void a() { std::cout << data_ << std::endl; }
private:
    int data_;
};

class B
{
public:
    B(): a_(new A(13)) { std::cout << "B()" << std::endl; }
    ~B() { std::cout << "~B()" << std::endl; }
    std::function<void()> getf()
    {
        return [=]() { a_->a(); };
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<A> a_;
};

int main()
{
    std::function<void()> f;
    {
        B b;
        f = b.getf();
    }
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Here it looks like I'm capturing `a_` shared pointer by value, but when I run it on Linux (GCC 4.6.1), this is printed:

```
A(13)
B()
~B()
~A()
0
```

Obviously, 0 is wrong, because A is already destroyed. It looks like `this` is actually captured and is used to look up `this->a_`. My suspicion is confirmed when I change the capture list from `[=]` to `[=,a_]`. Then the correct output is printed and the lifetime of the objects is as expected:

```
A(13)
B()
~B()
13
~A()
```

**The question:**

Is this behaviour specified by the standard, implementation-defined, or undefined? Or I'm crazy and it's something entirely different?

Comment: I think it's by the standard as a_ usually resolves to this->a_, unless you explicitly tell it to copy a_.

Comment: Seems entirely legit to me - the only variable in scope is `this`. It'd be *surprising* if a pointer were just magically member-dereferenced! A nice question, though, and a great warning for the kids not to use the lazy captures `[=]`/`[&]` recklessly.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> Is this behaviour specified by the standard

Yes. Capturing member variables is always done via capturing `this`; it is the only way to access a member variable. In the scope of a member function `a_` is equivalent to `(*this).a_`. This is true in Lambdas as well.

Therefore, if you use `this` (implicitly or explicitly), then you must ensure that the object remains alive while the lambda instance is around.

If you want to capture it by value, you must explicitly do so:

```
std::function<void()> getf()
{
    auto varA = a_;
    return [=]() { varA->a(); };
}
```

If you need a spec quote:

> The lambda-expression’s compound-statement yields the function-body ( 8.4 ) of the function call operator, but for purposes of name lookup (3.4), determining the type and value of this (9.3.2) and transforming id-expressions referring to non-static class members into class member access expressions using (*this) ( 9.3.1 ),
>   the compound-statement is considered in the context of the lambda-expression.

Comment: IMHO, one of the most horrible gotchas of lambdas. I just hope all compilers eventually add a big fat warning for this.

Comment: @Martin: it's as bad as retaining a reference to a member variable of a destructed object. When an object is destructed, you should usually think think twice before using anything you got from it.

Comment: @Martin: Why would you warn for that? If the lambda were being used internally in an algorithm, it would be perfectly fine. He only ran into a problem because he wae _returning_ the lambda to someone.

Comment: @Dani but it's not an error to return a `shared_ptr` to a member. It seems like a potential common error, as I ran into it when converting existing code. I do think there be a warning (at least on `-Wextra`), and could be silenced when you access the member explicitly via `this->`, for example, or add it to the capture list.

Comment: @Nicol - I would want a warning, when a member wouldn't be explicitly accessed via `this->` in the lambda, because it is completely non-obvious that a lambda that is capturing everything by value is only capturing the `this` *pointer* by value, and not the members, although you can then reference the members without the this pointer inside the lambda. (I know that it makes sense from an implementation POV, and it also makes sense if the lambda is only used inside the member function, but as soon as the lambda is passed around you have a crash waiting to happen!)

Comment: @Martin: C++ does not exist to protect you from yourself. Just as one can use naked pointers incorrectly, or even pass `this` around incorrectly, C++ does not stop you from storing `this` implicitly in an object and allowing you to return it. And you only have "a crash waiting to happen" if there are no other precautions taken to prevent access to an object instance that has been destroyed. Something implicit perhaps, like using signals/slots for callbacks and such. This allows one to unregister the callback when the object instance is destroyed, and thus no "crash waiting to happen".

Comment: @AlexB: That would make `-Wextra` useless, because every _safe_ use of it would now either require explicitly typing `this->` or explicitly including `this` in the list (which means you can't use `[=]` anymore). Lambdas exist for the sole purpose of making code _shorter_, not longer; there is nothing you can do with lambdas that you couldn't without them. They're just syntactic sugar. And remember: using the internally within a function call is almost always safe, and that is the majority of use cases for Lambdas.

Comment: @Nicol: to me, the problem here isn't that nasty old C++ is letting me shoot myself in the foot, the problem is that the lambda's "capture by value" silently captures `this` rather than `_a`. That's worth an optional warning, IMO, whether the lambda is returned or not. If the warning encouraged you to write `(*this)._a` explicitly, then it would be obvious that it's `this` that is captured. Compilers warn for other things that are much less dangerous and less subtly incorrect.

Comment: @SteveJessop: And how do you detect the difference between a safe use of a lambda and an unsafe one?

Comment: @SteveJessop: There is nothing dangerous or subtly incorrect about implicitly capturing `this`. That's what you asked for when you used `[=]`. You're basically wanting to penalize everyone who uses Lambdas because of this one potential problem that only arises in the event of using lambdas as callbacks. And even then, it only arises when you have done something you didn't think about. Just like many other issues in C++ that compilers _don't_ warn about.

Comment: @Nicol: it is false that using this lambda internally within a function call is "always safe". Using it internally or externally, it still captures `this` (which appears nowhere in the source of the lambda), not `_a`. You could reset or otherwise modify the smart pointer without leaving scope, and if your expectation was that `_a` was captured by value, then your code would still be wrong. The whole point of optional warnings is to identify places where a fairly reasonable programmer expectation is incorrect, and although incorrect it's not totally unreasonable to expect `[=]` to capture `_a`.

Comment: @Nicol: I don't want to "penalize" anyone, I think an optional warning is justified. You don't have to enable it, so I find it surprising that you're so passionate that it shouldn't even be available for others. You find it obvious that `[=]` captures `this`, not `_a`, because you are entirely familiar with the standard in that area. That's great, but compilers warn for far less difficult subtleties of the language.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I agree with SteveJessop, it would have made more sense to not capture `this` when specifying `[=]`, only with `[&]`.

Comment: Any lambda functions (functional-wise) that are sufficiently "stateful" in that they depend on the existence of other objects are better implemented as an abstract base class implementation (i.e. with interface name, virtual method name, and then a named concrete implementation), which in turn captures all of its dependencies in `shared_ptr` and again return itself (the function object) via a `shared_ptr`. I have to say that future of C++ ***does not bode well*** for people who discourage `shared_ptr`. (Though `shared_ptr` has its own pitfalls and workarounds as well.)