# How to capture a single class data member in a lambda expression?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm aware of the following question: [C++11 lambdas: member variable capture gotcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764564/c11-lambdas-member-variable-capture-gotcha). Furthermore, I'm aware of the need to capture class members by capturing the `this` pointer, as the answer to this question clearly states.

> Yes. Capturing member variables is always done via capturing this; it is the only way to access a member variable.

**However**, capturing the `this` pointer **captures all class members**. Is it possible to restrict which class members are captured? For example, is is possible to **capture a single class member**?

I know the following doesn't work but is it possible to achieve?

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() : mBar1(1), mBar2(2) {}

    void doBar()
    {
        auto test = [this->mBar1]()
            {
                std::cout << mBar1 << "\n";
                // Trying to access 'mBar2' here would fail to compile...
            };

        test();
    }

    int mBar1;
    int mBar2;
};
```

From the comments:

> Why do you need this?

I don't *need* to do this. I'm just curious about understanding whether this is possible and if so how to do it.

Comment: Why do you need this? Can you not trust yourself?

Comment: @EdHeal This question isn't necessarily about the _need_ for this versus understanding if it's possible/how to do it. However, I think there is some value in a self documenting lambda expression that clear states which state is captured, how it captured (i.e., by value/reference), and the source of the captured state.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using C++11 you will have to capture `this`.

However, in C++14 you can capture arbitrary expressions, either by value:

```
[mBar1 = this->mBar1]() { ... }
```

or reference:

```
[&mBar1 = this->mBar1]() { ... }
```

Comment: @Brian I am restricted to a C++11 compiler currently. However, you're correct that my usage of the C++11 tag doesn't imply that I don't want to know that this is possible in C++14 or any other future/proposed C++ standard but that it is appropriate to state that it's not possible in C++11.

Comment: The question may be tagged "C++11", but realize this: C++14 added a solution, which would not have happened if there was already a good solution in C++11. We can't _prove_ a negative, but this at least makes it _believable_ that no C++11 solution exists.

Answer (score 7):

If you are able to use a C++14 compiler, you can use

```
auto test = [&bar = this->mBar1]()
{
    std::cout << bar<< "\n";
};
```

If you are restricted to using a C++11 compiler, you'll have to capture `this`.