# Capturing only a specific member of a class inside lambda

Tags: c++, lambda

I understand that we have to capture the *this pointer in the lambda to access any of the member variables inside the lambda. Now, why can't I capture only a single member of an object inside the lambda?

```
 #include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo () : a(5) {}
    void func ()
    {
        [this->a] () { std::cout << a; } ();
    }

private:
        int a;
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.func();
}
```

This code above throws me a syntax error,

```
<source>: In member function 'void Foo::func()':
<source>:9:14: error: expected ',' before '->' token
    9 |         [this->a] () { std::cout << a; } ();
      |              ^~
<source>:9:14: error: expected identifier before '->' token
```

I tried this in godbolt. org with gcc 11.1

[Edit] I understand that there are ways to capture a single member of an object but I want to understand why `this->member` is invalid in the capture list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to capture a single class data member in a lambda expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653624/how-to-capture-a-single-class-data-member-in-a-lambda-expression)

Comment: No, I understand that there are various solutions to this problem but my question is why is this not valid? I want to understand that.

Answer (score 2):

```
void func ()
{
    [a = this->a] () { std::cout << a; } ();
}
```

You need to specify the name of the variable to access it in the lambda.

**EDIT:**

***Lambda under the hood:***

When a lambda definition is executed, for each variable that the lambda captures, a clone of that variable is made (with an identical name) inside the lambda. These cloned variables are initialized from the outer scope variables of the same name at this point.

So `[this->a]` doesn't make sense. Compiler need to allocate space for captured variable, and to make that memory accessible it needs a name.

Comment: Yes, I know this solution but why do I have to do this? This is similar to 
```
void func ()
{
    int a = this->a;
    [a] () { std::cout << a; } ();
}```
Right?
I'm just caching the value of this->a into a variable a in the func()'s stack.

My question is why can't I just capture this->a? What's the limitation?

Comment: @MuttalKadavul check out the updated answer, I think this is what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Yes, I just found that. Thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

> but my question is why is this not valid

First thing to understand is how are lambdas expressed behind the scenes. Compiler replaces it with an anonymous class with overloaded `operator()`. For example, a following lambda:

```
[a](int b){return a + b;}
```

Could be converted by the compiler to following class:

```
class __lambda_some_random_unique_identifier {
public:
    int operator() (int b) const {
        return a + b;
    }
private:
    int a;
};
```

Now, if you would allow expression `this->a` to be on capture list, how should it be translated to a class member? Arguably, it could be called `a`, but if you allow expression `this->a`, then why not `this->a.size()` (assuming `a` is `std::vector`)? How would it be named then?

---

Since the problem can be easily solved with named captures *or* with capturing `this` as a whole, there's no good reason to add handling complex expressions to that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you point me to some official documentation or something? I would want to read more about it.

Comment: @MuttalKadavul consider that when you write `auto f = [x](){};` then `x` has to meanings: It is the name of the captured variable and at the same time it is the name of the variable you can use inside the lambda. With `this->x` this cannot work. I doubt you can find an explanation of why your case does not work (other than this answer of course), but when you read about lambdas you will find that this case isnt mentioned

Comment: @MuttalKadavul There's [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), but it may be a challenging read (although it's still better than C++ standard). It doesn't explain directly why you cannot use `this->a` on capture list, but it follows from the definition of lambda (as in the answer). I don't have any other resource at hand, which would explain how the lambda works internally, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Its just a matter of what syntax is valid and what is not. Your issue isn't specific to `this`. You also cannot capture member of another object like this:

```
struct foo { int x; };

int main() {
    foo obj;
    foo* f = &obj;
    auto l = [f->x](){};
}
```

While this is ok:

```
struct foo { int x; };

int main() {
    foo obj;
    foo* f = &obj;
    auto l = [x = f->x](){};
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I can't capture member of another object within the class also, but why?
Why the second code is valid and not the first one? Is it just because of the complexity in translating the lambdas? Or something else?

Comment: @MuttalKadavul the even less helpful answer is: Because thats not how it works. You could as well ask "Why can I not declare a lambda like this `auto f = return true;`?". For the more helpful answer see Yksisarvinens answer, there are some good arguments why it doesnt work like that. I see no reason why it would be impossible in principle (though it would require some new rules how to get a name that you can use to refer to the member inside the lambda)