# Capturing the 'this' pointer in an embedded lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have a lambda called from another lambda, and in the 'inner' lambda I don't seem to be capturing the `this` pointer correctly. Is there something wrong with my syntax here? My code is of the form:

```
void MyClass::myFunction(double newValue)
{
    auto innerLambda = [this]() -> bool    // I've also tried '[&]' here
                       { 
                           if (this -> State == State1)
                               return true;
                           else
                               return false;
                       };

     auto outerLambda = [&](double newValue)   
                        {
                            if (innerLambda())
                            {
                                // Do something
                                ...
                            }
                            else
                            {
                               // Do something else
                               ...
                            }
                        };  

     outerLambda(newValue);
}
```

If I put a debug breakpoint in `outerLambda` and examine the contents of the `this` pointer, then everything is present and correct, but if I do the same in `innerLambda` then the `this` pointer seems to be pointing to garbage.

Comment: [`this` comes out the same in both](https://ideone.com/rHgrWZ) in this near-exact reproduction of your code, so there's probably something that you're not showing.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @zneak Guilty as charged; in my actual code, outerLambda is a Qt slot which is stored within a QList of QMetaObject::Connections. I'll  try to create a better example when I next get the opportunity, which will probably be about 16 hours from now.

Comment: Most likely that the outmost object went out of scope and the pointer is garbage. See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764564/c11-lambdas-member-variable-capture-gotcha

Comment: I found that reproducing the whole Qt signal-slot structure of the original code in a stand-alone example was a daunting task. Nevertheless, I found that if I just moved the contents of `innerLambda` into a separate member function (which, being a member of the same object, had the same `this` pointer by definition), then everything worked _exactly_ as it should have done. There's obviously something rather esoteric happening in the way that the scope is captured when lambdas collide with the Qt meta-object system.